# HUE of an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

How to change HUE of an UIImage

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically change the hue of UIImage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555071/how-to-programmatically-change-the-hue-of-uiimage)