# How to programmatically change the hue of UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image-processing, hue

I am very new to the image processing. I have to implement hue effect in my iPhone application project. Therefore, I need to change the hue of `UIImage`. Please provide me any sample code or tutorial link for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First, you need to decide if you are making an image a *fixed hue*, or *rotating the existing hue*.  Examples of both are shown below.

[image: Hue changes]

### Fixed hue

Fixing the hue can be done using the standard drawing tools - just make sure the blend mode is set to `kCGBlendModeHue`, and draw with the appropriate hue.  This is derived from Nitish's solution, although I found that making `saturation` less than `1.0` had inconsistent results.  This method does allow varying the alpha, but for true saturation other than 100% you will probably need a second round of drawing.

```
- (UIImage*) imageWithImage:(UIImage*) source fixedHue:(CGFloat) hue alpha:(CGFloat) alpha;
// Note: the hue input ranges from 0.0 to 1.0, both red.  Values outside this range will be clamped to 0.0 or 1.0.
{
    // Find the image dimensions.
    CGSize imageSize = [source size];
    CGRect imageExtent = CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height);

    // Create a context containing the image.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
    [source drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

    // Draw the hue on top of the image.
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeHue);
    [[UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:1.0 brightness:1 alpha:alpha] set];
    UIBezierPath *imagePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageExtent];
    [imagePath fill];

    // Retrieve the new image.
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return result;
}
```

### Rotated hue

To rotate the hue, you need Core Image filters.  The code below converts the UIImage to a CIImage, and then converts the result back to UIImage for display.  Depending on where your image comes from, you may be able to avoid one or both of these steps.

Conveniently, the very first example in the [Core Image Programming Guide: Using Core Image Filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html) uses the CIHueAdjust filter.

```
// #import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
// Partially from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_tasks/ci_tasks.html
- (UIImage*) imageWithImage:(UIImage*) source rotatedByHue:(CGFloat) deltaHueRadians;
{
    // Create a Core Image version of the image.
    CIImage *sourceCore = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[source CGImage]];

    // Apply a CIHueAdjust filter
    CIFilter *hueAdjust = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
    [hueAdjust setDefaults];
    [hueAdjust setValue: sourceCore forKey: @"inputImage"];
    [hueAdjust setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: deltaHueRadians] forKey: @"inputAngle"];
    CIImage *resultCore = [hueAdjust valueForKey: @"outputImage"];

    // Convert the filter output back into a UIImage.
    // This section from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7797578/1318452
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef resultRef = [context createCGImage:resultCore fromRect:[resultCore extent]];
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resultRef];
    CGImageRelease(resultRef);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Dondragmer, thanks for the brilliant answer. Do you know if we can avoid setting a hue for transparent areas of the UIImage?

Comment: Hey Sid, I've same issue applying hue to only opaque part of the image. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Swift version is below. No problems with opacity, either.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void) changeToHue:(float)hue saturation:(float)saturation {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
    UIView *hueBlend = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    hueBlend.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:1 alpha:1];
    CGContextDrawImage(context, self.bounds, self.image.CGImage);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeHue);
    [hueBlend.layer renderInContext:context];
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Apple's Swift blog, I came across this photo filtering app tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=16

The following is the sample code edited to create a contained method that returns a UIImage with a random hue applied.

```
func applyHue(source: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    // Create a place to render the filtered image
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    // Create an image to filter
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: source)

    // Create a random color to pass to a filter
    let randomColor = [kCIInputAngleKey: (Double(arc4random_uniform(314)) / 100)]

    // Apply a filter to the image
    let filteredImage = inputImage!.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHueAdjust", withInputParameters: randomColor)

    // Render the filtered image
    let renderedImage = context.createCGImage(filteredImage, fromRect: filteredImage.extent)

    // Return a UIImage
    return UIImage(CGImage: renderedImage)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift version of Dondragmer's rotating code above

```
// Convert the filter output back into a UIImage.
// This section from http://stackoverflow.com/a/7797578/1318452
func imageWithImage(source: UIImage, rotatedByHue: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    // Create a Core Image version of the image.
    let sourceCore = CIImage(CGImage: source.CGImage)
    // Apply a CIHueAdjust filter
    let hueAdjust = CIFilter(name: "CIHueAdjust")
    hueAdjust.setDefaults()
    hueAdjust.setValue(sourceCore, forKey: "inputImage")
    hueAdjust.setValue(CGFloat(rotatedByHue), forKey: "inputAngle")
    let resultCore  = hueAdjust.valueForKey("outputImage") as CIImage!
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    let resultRef = context.createCGImage(resultCore, fromRect: resultCore!.extent())
    let result = UIImage(CGImage: resultRef)
    return result!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking Dondragmer's excellent fixed hue example as a starting point. Here is my modification, to fix the problem of transparent areas being set with the same hue.

```
- (UIImage*) imageWithImage:(NSString *)name fixedHue:(CGFloat) hue alpha:(CGFloat) alpha;
// Note: the hue input ranges from 0.0 to 1.0, both red.  Values outside this range will be clamped to 0.0 or 1.0.
{
    UIImage *source = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

    // Find the image dimensions.
    CGSize imageSize = [source size];
    CGRect imageExtent = CGRectMake(0,0,imageSize.width,imageSize.height);

    // Create a context containing the image.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [source drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

    // Setup a clip region using the image
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, source.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, imageExtent, source.CGImage);

    //[[UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:1.0 brightness:1 alpha:alpha] set];
    CGContextFillRect(context, imageExtent);

    // Draw the hue on top of the image.
    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageExtent, source.CGImage);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeHue);
    [[UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:1.0 brightness:1 alpha:alpha] set];
    UIBezierPath *imagePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageExtent];
    [imagePath fill];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context); // remove clip region

    // Retrieve the new image.
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

Thanks to:

[How to change hue of UIIMAGE having transparent area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962645/how-to-change-hue-of-uiimage-having-transparent-area)

[CGContextClipToMask UIImage Mask Invert Up and Down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141366/cgcontextcliptomask-uiimage-mask-invert-up-and-down)

Comment: thanks this is just what I was looking for, however could I make a small suggestion? I would change `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize)` to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0)` so that the image scale is maintained across devices. Of course the opaque bool can be different if required.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5.0 updated from @JonLoard

```
 func changeHue(_ image: UIImage, hueValue:CGFloat)->UIImage?{
    if let sourceCGImage = image.cgImage{
        let sourceCore = CIImage(cgImage: sourceCGImage)
        // Apply a CIHueAdjust filter
        let hueAdjust = CIFilter(name: "CIHueAdjust")
        hueAdjust?.setDefaults()
        hueAdjust?.setValue(sourceCore, forKey: "inputImage")
        hueAdjust?.setValue(CGFloat(hueValue), forKey: "inputAngle")
        if let resultCore  = hueAdjust?.value(forKey: "outputImage") as? CIImage{
            let context = CIContext(options: nil)
            if let resultRef = context.createCGImage(resultCore, from: resultCore.extent){
                let result = UIImage(cgImage: resultRef,scale: 1,orientation: image.imageOrientation)
                return result
            }
        }
        
    }
    return image
}
```