# Get and change hue of SKSpriteNode's SKColor(HSBA)?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, hsb

A SKSpriteNode's SKColor has a way to be created with Hue, Saturation, Brightness & Alpha:

```
    let myColor = SKColor(hue: 0.5, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
 mySprite.color = myColor
```

How do I get at the hue of a `SKSpriteNode` and make a change to it? eg, divide it by 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `SKSpriteNode` is a node that draws a texture (optionally blended with a color), an image, a colored square. So, this is it's nature.

When you make an `SKSpriteNode`, you have an **instance property** that represent the texture used to draw the sprite called also [texture](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skspritenode/1520011-texture)

Since **iOS 9.x**, we are able to retrieve an image from a texture following the code below. In this example I call my `SKSpriteNode` as `spriteBg`:

```
let spriteBg = SKSpriteNode.init(texture: SKTexture.init(imageNamed: "myImage.png"))

if let txt = spriteBg.texture {
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                let image : UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage:txt.cgImage())
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions and forgot this code..
            }
}
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11557563/1894067) interesting answer, we can translate it to a more confortable **Swift 3.0** version:

```
func imageWith(source: UIImage, rotatedByHue: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        // Create a Core Image version of the image.
        let sourceCore = CIImage(cgImage: source.cgImage!)
        // Apply a CIHueAdjust filter
        guard let hueAdjust = CIFilter(name: "CIHueAdjust") else { return source }
        hueAdjust.setDefaults()
        hueAdjust.setValue(sourceCore, forKey: "inputImage")
        hueAdjust.setValue(CGFloat(rotatedByHue), forKey: "inputAngle")
        let resultCore  = hueAdjust.value(forKey: "outputImage") as! CIImage!
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        let resultRef = context.createCGImage(resultCore!, from: resultCore!.extent)
        let result = UIImage(cgImage: resultRef!)
        return result
}
```

So, finally with the previous code we can do:

```
if let txt = spriteBg.texture {
            if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
                let image : UIImage = UIImage.init(cgImage:txt.cgImage())
                let changedImage = imageWith(source: image, rotatedByHue: 0.5)
                spriteBg.texture = SKTexture(image: changedImage)
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions or bought a new iphone
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not in a place to be able to test this right now, but looking at the `UIColor` documentation (UIColor and SKColor are basically the same thing), you should be able to use the `.getHue(...)` function retrieve the color's components, make changes to it, then set the SKSpriteNode's color property to the new value. the `.getHue(...)` function "Returns the components that make up the color in the HSB color space."

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621949-gethue

Comment: I saw this when researching, and tried variations of using it. But my coding sucks so hard I was getting nowhere with it. Going backwards, actually.

Comment: @Confused 1. Your code don't sucks. -  2. You've made an interesting and  good question.