# CoreImage CIHueAdjust filter giving wrong colors

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I am working with the code from Dondragmer's 'Rotated Hue' example from this question: [How to programmatically change the hue of UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555071/how-to-programmatically-change-the-hue-of-uiimage)

However, I am getting very different results than what I'd expect. I'm expecting the hue change to give similar results to changing the hue in Photoshop, but the changes aren't at all similar.

To illustrate, using this source image:

[image: source image]

A pi/4 rotation in Photoshop gives this:

[image: 45 degree rotation Photoshop]

Using Dondragmer's code I get:

[image: 45 degree rotation CIHueAdjust]

Likewise, a 180 degree rotation in Photoshop gives this:

[image: 180 degree rotation Photoshop]

But the CIHueAdjust filter produces:

[image: 180 degree rotation CIHueAdjust]

My code:

```
- (CGImageRef)changeHueOfImage(CGImageRef)source By:(NSInteger)angle
{
    CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:source];

    // Convert degrees to radians
    CGFloat angleRadians = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(angle);

    // Use the Core Image CIHueAdjust filter to change the hue
    CIFilter *hueFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
    [hueFilter setDefaults];
    [hueFilter setValue:image forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [hueFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:angleRadians] forKey:@"inputAngle"];
    image = [hueFilter outputImage];

    // Save the modified image
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef result = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:[image extent]];

    return result;
}
```

My questions:

1. Am I misunderstanding what the CIHueAdjust filter does?
2. Do I need to consider how brightness and saturation factor into the filter?
3. How do I replicate the Photoshop behavior
4. Just generally, why are the results so different?

Comment: My question is why aren't you showing a single line of code?  What kind of number are you passing to CIHueAdjust?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue when trying to update the brightness of a `CIImage`. The problem is that `CoreImage` works in `RGB` space, and modifying the hue, saturation or brightness should be done in `HSV` space.

What I ended up doing was using this snippet I found [here](https://gist.github.com/bjorndagerman/3734441) to manipulate each pixel. There's probably a better way but I created a `UIColor` with the `RGB` values of each pixel, got the `HSV` values from that color, updated the component I wanted to update, created a new UIColor and used the `RGB` values of that color to modify the image.

```
CGImageRef imageRef = [img CGImage];
uint width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
uint height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
unsigned char *pixels = malloc(height*width*4); //1d array with size for every pixel. Each pixel has the components: Red,Green,Blue,Alpha

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, 4*width, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast); //our quartz2d drawing env
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);

for (int y=0;y<height;++y){
    for (int x=0;x<width;++x){
        int idx = (width*y+x)*4; //the index of pixel(x,y) in the 1d array pixels

        //Pixel manipulation here

        //red = pixels[idx]
        //green = piexls[idx+1]
        //blue = pixels[idx+2]
        //alpha = pixels[idx+3]

        //pixels[idx] = NEW_RED_VALUE

        //Please note that this assumes an image format with alpha stored in the least significant bit.
        //See kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast for more info. 
        //Change if needed and also update bitmapInfo provided to CGBitmapContextCreate
    }
}


imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
free(pixels);

//load our new image
UIImage* newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

**NOTE:** I didn't write this code, [I found it here](https://gist.github.com/bjorndagerman/3734441) and pasted it here in case the gist is deleted. [All credit to bjorndagerman@github](https://github.com/bjorndagerman)

You might get better performance if you implement the `RGB -> HSV -> RGB` conversion yourself, and if you're trying to execute this filter multiple times per second, you will see a performance hit, but it's my best suggestion, I couldn't find a way to modify Hue, Saturation or Brightness in `HSV` space with `CoreImage`.

**Update**: as @dfd mentioned in the comments, you could also write a custom kernel for a filter that does these calculations, it would be much faster but you'll need to google how to convert RGB to HSV and back.

Comment: "CoreImage works in RGB space, and modifying the hue, saturation or brightness should be done in HSV space"  "You might get better performance if you implement the RGB -> HSV -> RGB conversion yourself"  Huh!?  You are way off.

Comment: @ElTomato care to elaborate? I meant he'd get a better performance if he does the math himself instead of creating two UIColors per pixel like I did.

Comment: His or her problem is likely to be passing the number of degrees other than the number of radians to CIHueAdjust.  Besides, what you show is pointless.  Why would anyone want to convert RGB colors into HSV and then back into RGB colors?  All you have to do is change the color space.

Comment: @ElTomato Failure to convert degrees to radians is a good guess, but as you can see, I am making that conversion before using the value. (I admit I made that mistake in my very first attempt at this code, but I solved that problem long before posting here :-) So let's hear your next idea!

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I suspect my problem does have something to do with how I'm using color spaces, so I think you're on the right track--but I've tried supplying various color space options to Core Image and haven't found anything that works. As it happens, after reading your post I manually implemented a pixel-by-pixel conversion and got the desired output; but at this point I really want to know the correct way to do this with Core Image, which is supposed to be much faster at this kind of job.

Comment: @RobLyman unfortunately, on iOS Core Image is as powerful as it is limited. Unlike in macOS, you can't write your own filters, and the default filters perform the operation using the RGB values, which I don't think is directly related to the ColorSpace, and those filters don't have a color space property anyway. Like I mentioned, I ran into a very similar roadblock and had to do just that one operation pixel-by-pixel. If you give up and end up using my solution, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez, huh? I've written a few `CIKernels` for iOS, registering them so that I get the full capabilities of a `CIFilter`. These work in iOS 9+, as they use GLSL. And as of iOS 11 you can utilize Metal 2. I'm not claiming that this is the *correct* solution - or even a *possible* solution to the OP but I *am* saying your second sentence is 100% incorrect as of September 2015 (iOS 9).

Comment: @dfd thanks for your comment, I don't remember where I read that custom kernels weren't available on iOS, but it was probably out of date. I updated my answer based on your comment, though I don't have experience with custom kernels to implement something like that for an SO answer, and I've already wasted too much time on this answer.

Comment: They weren't before iOS 9 - IMHO a big issue when CoreImage was brought to iOS in version 5. Probably because of the GPU "horsepower"? Anyways, they are pretty easy to write  - if you know what you're doing. (Hint: I don't. At least enough to do RGB to HSV back to RGB. Sounds fairly easy though. I work at the pixel level - both color and warp (one-to-one translate and the ones surrounding the pixel being used) but not with color spaces. Hopefully the OP has enough to get his/her issue resolved....

Answer (score 1):

I never found an answer to my question: why does CIHueAdjust not give the expected result. But I did figure out alternative code that gives me the result I want:

```
#define Mask8(x) ( (x) & 0xFF )
#define R(x) ( Mask8(x) )
#define G(x) ( Mask8(x >> 8 ) )
#define B(x) ( Mask8(x >> 16) )
#define A(x) ( Mask8(x >> 24) )
#define RGBAMake(r, g, b, a) ( Mask8(r) | Mask8(g) << 8 | Mask8(b) << 16 | Mask8(a) << 24 )

- (CGImageRef)changeHueForImage:(CGImageRef)image by:(NSInteger)angle
{
    // Get size and allocate array of UIColors
    NSInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    NSInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(image);
    NSInteger count = width * height;

    // Draw image into pixel buffer
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    NSInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

    NSInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;

    UInt32 *bitmapPixels = (UInt32 *)calloc(count, sizeof(UInt32));

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapPixels, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);

    // Shift hue of every pixel
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // Get pixel
        UInt32 pixel = bitmapPixels[i];

        // Convert to HSBA
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:R(pixel)/255.0 green:G(pixel)/255.0 blue:B(pixel)/255.0 alpha:A(pixel)/255.0];
        CGFloat h, s, br, a;
        [color getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&br alpha:&a];

        // Shift by angle
        CGFloat angleRadians = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(angle);
        angleRadians /= 2.0f*M_PI;
        h += angleRadians;
        if (h > 1.0f || h < 0.0f) {
            h -= floor(h);
        }

        // Make new color
        UIColor *newColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:h saturation:s brightness:br alpha:a];

        // Convert back to RGBA
        CGFloat r, g, b;
        [newColor getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];

        // Set pixel
        bitmapPixels[i] = RGBAMake((UInt32)(r * 255.0), (UInt32)(g * 255.0), (UInt32)(b * 255.0), (UInt32)(a * 255.0));
    }

    // Create the new image and clean up
    CGImageRef newImg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    free(bitmapPixels);

    return newImg;
 }
```

I'm not thrilled with this solution; in particular, there is almost certainly something more efficient than relying on making a new `UIColor` for every pixel. But it shifts the hue of the image as expected.

Comment: Don't forget to `CGImageRelease(newImg);`

Comment: Also your alpha space was using 225 not 255; edited it for you!

Comment: Lastly, HSV space shifts from 0-1 not 0-2π so using radians isn't what you want but instead radians/2π; and you can also go out of bounds just by adding so you want to wrap w/ a modulo tactic. I've edited both of these in as well. Thanks for this post it helped save me a ton of time

Answer (score 0):

The input parameter for hue is represented in radians.

[image]

The following code allows you to enter a float from 0.0 to 1.0 representing 0 to 360 degrees.

```
extension UIImage {

    // CIHueAdjust
    
    func withHueAdjustment(hue: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        
        // angle
        
        let angle = deg2rad(hue * 360)
                
        // cgImage
        
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return self }
    
        // filter
        
        guard let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIHueAdjust") else { return self }
    
        filter.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: cgImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        
        // Hue
        
        filter.setValue(angle, forKey: kCIInputAngleKey)
    
        // result
        
        guard let result = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage else { return self }
    
        guard let newCgImage = CIContext(options: nil).createCGImage(result, from: result.extent) else { return self }
    
        return UIImage(cgImage: newCgImage, scale: self.scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    
    }
    
    func deg2rad(_ number: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        
        return (number * .pi) / 180
    
    }

}
```

**Usage**

```
    let myImage = UIImage.init(named: "someImage")
    
    let hueAdjustedImage = myImage?.withHueAdjustment(hue: 0.4)
```